# hist2D masked array - ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, heatmap, scatter

Something about the way I have masked zero values in my array is causing an error when doing his2d. I try:

```
x = ma.masked_array([0.17478785046728973, 0.21854713940370668, 0.7354304690743048,
                     1.1052309124767226, 0.3450562200956937, 0])

x[5] = ma.masked_all(1)

y = ma.masked_array([0.17478785046728973, 0.21854713940370668, 0.7354304690743048,
                     1.1052309124767226, 0.3450562200956937, 0])

plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

I think it doesn't like something to do with the decimals because this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-38bb844ac43e> in <module>()
      9                      1.1052309124767226, 0.3450562200956937, 0])
     10 
---> 11 plt.hist2d(c, d, bins = 10)
     12 plt.show()

/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist2d(x, y, bins, range, normed, weights, cmin, cmax, hold, data, **kwargs)
   2983         ret = ax.hist2d(x, y, bins=bins, range=range, normed=normed,
   2984                         weights=weights, cmin=cmin, cmax=cmax, data=data,
-> 2985                         **kwargs)
   2986     finally:
   2987         ax.hold(washold)

/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1817                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1818                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1819             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1820         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1821         if pre_doc is None:

/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in hist2d(self, x, y, bins, range, normed, weights, cmin, cmax, **kwargs)
   6300         range = __builtins__["range"]
   6301         h, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, range=bin_range,
-> 6302                                            normed=normed, weights=weights)
   6303 
   6304         if cmin is not None:

/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.pyc in histogram2d(x, y, bins, range, normed, weights)
    712         xedges = yedges = asarray(bins, float)
    713         bins = [xedges, yedges]
--> 714     hist, edges = histogramdd([x, y], bins, range, normed, weights)
    715     return hist, edges[0], edges[1]
    716 

/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.pyc in histogramdd(sample, bins, range, normed, weights)
    800         mindiff = dedges[i].min()
    801         if not np.isinf(mindiff):
--> 802             decimal = int(-log10(mindiff)) + 6
    803             # Find which points are on the rightmost edge.
    804             not_smaller_than_edge = (sample[:, i] >= edges[i][-1])

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

if I plot the array without my masked value against itself: `plt.hist2d(y, y, bins = 10)` then it *works*. Am I using the wrong method to mask? I was originally using that syntax to mask a 2D slice of a 3D array, so I am wondering if I am creating an array within an array unnecessarily.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down a bit more, thanks for the prompt.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftfGA.png).

Comment: I'm on Python 2 if that makes a difference...

Comment: I've made a fresh script (Py2.7), using the code above with these import statements: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import numpy.ma as ma` Perhaps one of these is wrong?

Comment: It works in "conda_root" environment so it seems to be a package... In another environment ("default") I get this warning: `/Users/eebp/anaconda/envs/Python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:779: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  if np.any(np.asarray(dedges[i]) <= 0):` How can I narrow down which package is causing this code to fail?

Comment: I'm also running Python 2.7 and running the same imports (on Windows), with `NumPy 1.14`. The most minimal debug functionality is provided in the module `pdb`.